# Validation message for a nullable integer value not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a `int?` field called **LoanedTo** in my database table and in my model it is defined as:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value should be an integer")]
public int? LoanedTo { get; set; }
```

On my view where I used this value, my validation does not seem to work.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    Loan Book To User (Id)
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoanedTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoanedTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

This means, when the user enters a string for the `LoanedTo` value they get no error message and the operation is not complete.

**Update**: I have referenced the following jQuery validation scripts in my View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add reference **Jquery** validation script or you can include **Layout** page which will automatically include the reference **Jquery** validation script.

Comment: Please look at the *Update* in the question.